# ArcGIS Pro's File Chooser not showing folders

Tags: arcgis-pro, windows-10

**Why is ArcGIS Pro's file chooser not showing folders?**

I have this weird issue that ArcGIS Pro's file chooser has no items. It's empty, i.e. no drives and no folders are shown. Also, there is no dialog title shown.

[image: Example Dialog]

For reproducing reasons, in the Event Viewer, I have following error:

[image]

I discovered that when I click on an unavailable network drive in Windows's file explorer, the explorer is not responding. I have to kill and restart the explorer process in the Task Manager.

**System:** Windows 10 (21H1), ArcGIS Pro 2.7.3

**Issue:** Domain User Account, Unavailable Network Drive, VPN (see answer to reproduce)

(https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was an unavailable (not accessible) network drive because I was not connected to the VPN.

(When accessing the network drive in Windows's file explorer, the explorer was not responding and I had to kill and restart the explorer process in the Task Manager.)

It looks like ArcGIS Pro has the same issue as others (and me) have experienced before with QGIS. See [QGIS 3 Installation fails - Windows 10 - Main Window not responding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371147/qgis-3-installation-fails-windows-10-main-window-not-responding/413351#413351).

But I think the underlying and real issue is somewhere to be found in a Windows 10 issue (not responding as expected by the applications).

For now, make sure your shared drives are accessible.

[image]

Note: If there is a better answer, I'll change the accepted answer.